# Hide div if a another div contains any text or content or html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to `display:block;` the wrapper div if the `div`'s within it contain any content, html, text or anything.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="display:none">

    <ul id="checkforcontent"></ul>
    <ul id="checkforcontent"></ul>
    <ul id="checkforcontent"></ul>
    <ul id="checkforcontent"></ul>

</div>
```

So for the above example if any one of the `<ul>` had any content in it e.g.:

```
<ul id="checkforcontent"><li>Hello</li></ul>
```

Then I'd like the `div#wrapper` to become `display:block;` otherwise if none of the `ul`'s have any content I still want it to remain hidden.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, will you always have 4 <ul> or is this dynamically created or just an example?

Comment: Note: ID of an element must be unique

Comment: I will always have 4 <ul>'s and they can have different ID's, doesn't need to always be checkforcontent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in oneline :

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$wrapper.toggle(!!$wrapper.find("ul>li").length);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12xeomeu/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much, how do I hire you? Lol

Comment: @KimTran Pls accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Thanks! :)
It was originally:
$wrapper.toggle(!!$wrapper.find("#checkforcontent li").length)
if anyone is wondering.

Comment: Missed that checkforcontent was ID and not a class - ID should be unique in a page, and this will not work properly if present multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether there is any text content and based on that set the display of the div

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$wrapper.toggle($wrapper.text().trim().length>0)
```

Note: ID of an element must be unique

Comment: Note that if li contains only non-text nodes (img / video etc tags), this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are any li-elements in the div and if there are, show the div:

```
var $div = $("#wrapper");
if ($div.find("li").length > 0) {
  $div.show();
}
```

Comment: How does this code know to check for the content inside the ul with the id checkforcontent?

Comment: The find-method searches the whole dom-tree inside the div. It will find the li-elements inside the ul-elements.